# How can I incorporate a PivotTable right into the source data on the sheet (using EPPlus)?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, epplus, epplus-4

I've been able to create a PivotTable separate from the raw/source data, but now I want to combine the two, with the PivotTable allowing filtering of the spreadsheet data by providing filters on the column heading row, like this:

[image]

I tried this code:

```
private void AddPivotTable()
{
    // The commented-out code below placess the PivotTable below the actual data, separate from it:
    //string colAlphaRowNum = string.Format("A{0}", locationWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row+5);
    // Here I am attempting to incorporate the PivotTable within the data itself (one row above it, actually)
    string colAlphaRowNum = "A5";
    ExcelAddressBase eab = locationWorksheet.Cells[colAlphaRowNum];
    ExcelRangeBase erb = locationWorksheet.Cells[6, 1, locationWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row, locationWorksheet.Dimension.End.Column];
    var pt = locationWorksheet.PivotTables.Add(eab, erb, "Pivotous");

    pt.RowFields.Add(pt.Fields[0]);
    pt.RowFields.Add(pt.Fields[1]);
    pt.RowFields.Add(pt.Fields[2]);
    pt.RowFields.Add(pt.Fields[3]);
    pt.RowFields.Add(pt.Fields[4]);
    pt.RowFields.Add(pt.Fields[5]);
    pt.MultipleFieldFilters = true;
    pt.RowGrandTotals = true;
    pt.ColumGrandTotals = true;
    pt.Compact = true;
    pt.CompactData = true;
    pt.GridDropZones = false;
    pt.Outline = false;
    pt.OutlineData = false;
    pt.ShowError = true;
    pt.ErrorCaption = "[error]";
    pt.ShowHeaders = true;
    pt.UseAutoFormatting = true;
    pt.ApplyWidthHeightFormats = true;
    pt.ShowDrill = true;
    pt.DataOnRows = false;

    pt.FirstHeaderRow = 1;  // first row has headers
    pt.FirstDataCol = 1;    // first col of data
    pt.FirstDataRow = 2;    // first row of data

    pt.TableStyle = TableStyles.Medium6; // There is a "custom" and several Dark, Light, and Medium options
}
```

...but this does not work. I get this dialog when I open the generated sheet:

[image]

If I select "Yes" this is what I see:

[image]

If I select "No", I see this:

[image]

...which is promising, but if I then drop down the "Row Labels", deselect the "(Select All)" and then select the first item ("Stern"), I see this:

[image]

This is not what I want; in the model (hand-crafted) sheet, deselecting "Select All" and then selecting a single item filters the data to just include that data ("Foster" in this case), like so:

[image]

...rather than replacing the first part of the data with a restricted PivotTable.

What do I need to do to make this work as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps my nomenclature was faulty, because I think what I really want is not necessarily a PivotTable, but the ability to filter.

And, although attempting to do it this way, which seems logical and is even theoretically correct:

```
using (var shortNameCell = locationWorksheet.Cells[rowToPop, SHORTNAME_BYDCBYLOC_COL])
{
    shortNameCell.Value = "Short Name";
    shortNameCell.Style.WrapText = false;
    shortNameCell.Style.Font.Size = 12;
    shortNameCell.AutoFilter = true;
}
using (var companyNameCell = locationWorksheet.Cells[rowToPop, COMPANYNAME_BYDCBYLOC_COL])
{
    . . .
    companyNameCell.AutoFilter = true;
}
using (var reasonDescCell = locationWorksheet.Cells[rowToPop, REASONDESC_BYDCBYLOC_COL])
{
    . . .
    reasonDescCell.AutoFilter = true;
}
using (var transTypeCell = locationWorksheet.Cells[rowToPop, TRANSTYPE_BYDCBYLOC_COL])
{
    . . .
    transTypeCell.AutoFilter = true;
}
```

...results in only the final column thus appointed to sport filtration abilities, the following works for all four:

```
locationWorksheet.Cells["A6:D6"].AutoFilter = true;
```

Using the last, I get the following:

[image]

### UPDATE

It was a Pivot Table that I needed after all, and what I did to get a start on how to accomplish what I need is shown in my auto-answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885179/is-there-a-sister-function-to-autofilter-in-excel-interop-that-works-for-col).